# How to identify the image of receipt and cut it?

Tags: python, ocr, object-detection

I have a set of images of receipt photos and I need to read them, however the readings I get are very bad because some images are rotated and have a background, so it occurred to me that I could identify the edges of the receipts and cut and rotate it, however I have not found a way to do it, I leave you an example of how I would like it to be:

[here I show the image as it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC2qu.jpg)

and the result I would like it: [here I show the image as I would like it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5AGU.jpg).

Thank you for indicating me which python libraries I could use or if you have much better examples, thank you.

Initially I removed the background:

```
from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('temp/receipt.jpg')
output = remove(img)
output.save('temp/receipt-wb.png')
```

and the following image remains: [image without background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F335P.png)

then I try to rotate it as they say here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/141818/como-enderezo-una-imagen-en-python,  but I can't do it, an error appears.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

imagen = cv2.imread('temp/receipt-wb.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

binaria = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

lineas = cv2.HoughLines(binaria, 1, np.pi/720, 1000)

angulos = []
for linea in lineas:
    theta = linea[0][1]
    angulos.append(theta)

veces = Counter(angulos)

angulo = veces.most_common()[0][0]

if angulo > np.pi/2:
    angulo = -angulo
print("[INFO] angulo: {:.5f}".format(angulo))

(h, w) = imagen.shape[:2]
centro = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(centro, -angulo, 1.0)
girada = cv2.warpAffine(imagen, M, (w, h),flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

cv2.imwrite('temp/receipt-wb-rotate.png', girada)

Result: 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 26>()
     23 # Recopilemos qué ángulos ha encontrado la transformada
     24 # de hough para cada una de las líneas halladas
     25 angulos = []
---> 26 for linea in lineas:
     27     theta = linea[0][1]
     28     angulos.append(theta)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `HoughLines` couldn't find any lines,  you cannot iterate `lineas`. Try to play around with its parameters or do a further preprocessing (maybe a dilate to "melt" the characters together?) and then try with HoughLines